# Collecting a list of files that doesn't have any data to add to your frame

Tags: r, excel, for-loop, append, na

I'm trying to load multiple excel files all into one data frame. Some of the files don't have any data in the sheet that I'm looking for, so I'm looking to write code that collects the files that do have data, but also tells me which files weren't included because they didn't have any data. The code I have written does tell me which ones don't have data if I simply 'print(i)' inside the no part of my ifelse statement. However, as soon as I try to do anything else instead of printing, it seems to just ignore me! It's infuriating. How can I collect the names of the files that haven't contributed towards the total data frame?

this works fine:

```
library(readxl)
files <- list.files(path="./sfiles", pattern = "*.xls", full.names = T)
  alldiasendcgmlist <- lapply(files,function(i){
 ifelse(nrow(i)==NULL, NULL, i$name<-i)
   x= read_excel(i,sheet=2,skip=4)

   ifelse(nrow(x)>1,  x$ID <- i, print(i))

     x
     })
```

but as soon as I want to collect these printings inside a vector, the vector just continues to remain empty:

```
library(readxl)
files <- list.files(path="./sfiles", pattern = "*.xls", full.names = T)
vectornodata <- character(0)

  alldiasendcgmlist <- lapply(files,function(i){
 ifelse(nrow(i)==NULL, NULL, i$name<-i)
   x= read_excel(i,sheet=2,skip=4)

   ifelse(nrow(x)>1,  x$ID <- i, nodata <- append(vectornodata, i))

     x
     })
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building your list of data frames without any logical conditions. Then afterwards run `Filter` to separate empty and non-empty elements. `Negate` (another high-order function) is used to return the opposite (i.e., `NULL` elements without `length`).

```
# BUILD NAMED LIST OF EMPTY AND NON-EMPTY DFs
alldiasendcgmlist <- lapply(files, function(i) read_excel(i,sheet=2,skip=4))    
alldiasendcgmlist <- setNames(alldiasendcgmlistl), gsub(".xls", "", basename(files)))

# EXTRACT ACTUAL DFs FROM FULL LIST
full_xlfiles <- Filter(length, alldiasendcgmlist)

# EXTRACT NULL ELEMENTS FROM FULL LIST    
empty_xlfiles <- Filter(function(df) Negate(length)(df), alldiasendcgmlist)
empty_xlfiles  <- names(empty_xlfiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use my own example to show what one can do. Simply make your function return a list and then use one of its elements to filter our empty data frames:

```
input <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

func <- function(x){
  list("square"=x^2, "even"= ifelse(x %% 2 == 0, TRUE, FALSE))
}

res <- lapply(1:6, func) # returns a list of lists
even_numbers <- input[sapply(res, function(x) x[[2]])] # use 2nd element to filter
```

In your case, you can use a boolean vector to identify files that are empty.